# setw and accentuated characters

Tags: c++, setw

I want to display a "pretty" list of countries and their ISO currency codes on C++.
The issue is that my data is in French and it has accentuated characters. That means that Algeria, actually is written "Algérie" and Sweden becomes "Suède".

```
map<string, string> currencies; /* ISO code for currency and country name: CAD/Canada */ 
for (auto &cursor: countries)
  cout << setw(15) << left << cursor.second << right << " - " cursor.first << endl;
```

If the map contains Algeria, Canada and Sweden the result comes out something like this:

```
Canada          - CAD
Algérie        - DZD
Suède          - SEK
```

Do you see how Algeria and Sweden are not "pretty"? That's because even though "Algérie" has 7 visible characters and "Suède" has 5, they "count" as one more for setw. The "é" in "Algérie" and the "è" in "Suède" "count" as two characters, because they are "special accentuated characters.

Is there an **elegant** and **simple** way to make sure that DZD and SEK get automatically aligned with CAD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert to using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`
2. Convert to using wide string constants (`L"stuff"` vs `"stuff"`)
3. Convert to using `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`
4. Use `setlocale` to set a UTF-8 locale
5. Use `wcout.imbue` to configure wcout for a UTF-8 locale

Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::locale loc("en_US.UTF-8");
    std::wcout.imbue(loc); 
    std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> dict 
        { {L"Canada",L"CAD"}, {L"Algérie",L"DZD"}, {L"Suède",L"SEK"} };
    for (const auto& [key, value]: dict) {
        std::wcout << std::setw(10) << key << L" = " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, Mike!